# Apply gradient to a non-square shape drawn with AddArc

Tags: iphone, gradient

I've got a couple of closed shapes that I'm drawing in an iPhone app using CGContextAddArc, and I'd like to apply a gradient to it but can't find any good examples.  Everything I've found that clips bounds to a drawn shape reference CGRect somewhere, but I need to clip the gradient bounds to a non-CGRect shape.  Any ideas/help?

I'm using xcode 4.2.1 with storyboard and iOS5, though these shapes are being drawn within a view programmatically.

The code I'm using to draw my non-square shapes:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//set context-based constants
double widthMiddle = self.frame.size.width/2;
double heightMiddle = self.frame.size.height/2;
double avgDimension = (widthMiddle + heightMiddle) / 2;
float arcRadius = avgDimension * .9;
float innerRadius = avgDimension * .4;

double startAngle = 2 * (sectionNumber - 1) * (M_PI / 3);
double endAngle = (2 * (sectionNumber * (M_PI / 3))) - [sectionSpacing doubleValue];
double interfaceAngle = [sectionSpacing doubleValue] * (innerRadius / arcRadius);
double ratingRadius = innerRadius + ((arcRadius-innerRadius) * percentGood);
double percentInterfaceAngle = interfaceAngle * (1-percentGood);

//NSLog(@"InterfaceAngle and percentInterfaceAngle are: %f/%f", interfaceAngle, percentInterfaceAngle);

//draw grey background shape
CGContextBeginPath(context);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, [lineWeight doubleValue]);
//CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, .65, .65, .65, 1);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, 1);


//outer arc
CGContextAddArc(context,                                                //context
                widthMiddle,                                            //X-value for center point of arc
                heightMiddle,                                           //Y-value for center point of arc
                arcRadius,                                              //Radius of the arc
                startAngle,                   //start angle in radians
                endAngle,    //end angle in radians (2pi = full circle)
                0);                                                     //Clockwise? 1 = true
//inner arc
CGContextAddArc(context,                                                //context
                widthMiddle,                                            //X-value for center point of arc
                heightMiddle,                                           //Y-value for center point of arc
                innerRadius,                                        //Radius of the arc
                endAngle - interfaceAngle,                                   //start angle in radians
                startAngle + interfaceAngle,                                                    //end angle in radians (2pi = full circle)
                1);                                                     //Clockwise? 1 = true
CGContextClosePath(context);



//CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, .65, .65, .65, 1);
//CGContextSetAlpha(context, .6);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`CGContextClip`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip) function, or maybe the [`CGContextEOClip`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextEOClip) function.

`CGContextClip` sets the context's clipping path to the intersection of its current clipping path and its current path, and then clears the current path.  `CGContextEOClip` does the same, but with a different way of handling "holes" in the path.  The different only matters if you have a path that intersects itself, or contains multiple closed subpaths.

Comment: Yep!  That did it.  Thanks for the help, and sorry about the (long) delayed confirmation.